# Wrapping a matrix block

Tags: matrix, loop, batch

I'm outputting fields from a Matrix block, how do I then wrap all outputted fields from 'artworkFile' that are available with some HTML. Not individually wrapped, but all outputted fields.

Current Code:

```
{% case "artworkFile" %}
{% for asset in block.downloadUrl %}
 <a href="{{ asset.getUrl() }}" target="_blank">
 <div class="file {{ block.platform }} gutter-bottom--half"></div></a>
{% endfor %}
```

Desired Output

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="asseturl1.png>
   <div class="file exampleplatform1 gutter-bottom--half"></div>
  </a>
  <a href="asseturl2.png>
   <div class="file exampleplatform2 gutter-bottom--half"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Matrix Setup
[image]

Comment: The use case is missing here, which makes your question hard to answer – you might want to include more of your current template code. Is there are reason why you can't just wrap the Matrix loop in a container, i.e. `<div class="wrapper">{% for block in myMatrixField %}...{% endfor %}</div>`?

Comment: That seems to wrap each block in a 'wrapper' I want it to wrap all outputted blocks. I will update my question for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Without understanding your use case or having the context of your full template and/or Matrix loop, it's very difficult to provide a good answer.

If you only want to "wrap all outputted blocks" in a container, it's as easy as putting the Matrix loop in a container, e.g.:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    {% for block in entry.myMatrixFieldHandle %}
        {% switch block.type %}
            {% case 'artworkText' %}
                ...
            {% case 'artworkImageSingle' %}
                ...
            {% case 'artworkImageDouble' %}
                ...
            {% case 'artworkFile' %}
            {% for asset in block.downloadUrl %}
                <a href="{{ asset.getUrl() }}" target="_blank">
                    <div class="file {{ block.platform }} gutter-bottom--half"></div>
                </a>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endswitch %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Based on your comments, however, I suspect that what you really want is to only wrap the markup for all your `artworkFile` blocks.

If that is the case, you have to consider the fact that if you want to wrap all of the `artworkFile` blocks in a single container and not the other block types, then these `artworkFile` blocks will necessarily be removed from the general flow/chronology of your overall Matrix field. This may be exactly what you want, or a side effect you haven't considered - just wanted to mention it. (It also means that you could actually just move the `artworkFile` blocks to a separate Matrix field altogether, if that'd make any of this easier).

Anyway, there's at least a couple of ways to achieve the above with your current setup.

First, you can opt to remove the `artworkFile` switch case from your current Matrix loop, and create a secondary loop which only loops on `artworkFile` blocks somewhere else in your template. This secondary loop is then wrapped in a `<div class="wrapper">` container, e.g.:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    {% for block in entry.myMatrixFieldHandle.type('artworkFile') %}
        {% for asset in block.downloadUrl %}
        <a href="{{ asset.getUrl() }}" target="_blank">
            <div class="file {{ block.platform }} gutter-bottom--half"></div>
        </a>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Another option is to leave the `artworkFile` switch in your current Matrix loop, but instead of outputting the markup directly, you can cache it in an array – this is done by first putting the markup in a variable by wrapping the block markup in a `{% set %}` tag pair, adding that variable to an array declared outside the loop, and finally print the collected markup by joining the contents of that array inside a container, e.g.:

```
{# Create an empty array outside the loop #}
{% set artworkFileBlocks = [] %}
{% for block in entry.myMatrixFieldHandle %}
    {% switch block.type %}
        {% case 'artworkText' %}
            ...
        {% case 'artworkImageSingle' %}
            ...
        {% case 'artworkImageDouble' %}
            ...
        {% case 'artworkFile' %}
        {# Cache the markup for the artworkFile block to a variable #}
        {% set artworkFileBlock %}
            {% for asset in block.downloadUrl %}
                <a href="{{ asset.getUrl() }}" target="_blank">
                    <div class="file {{ block.platform }} gutter-bottom--half"></div>
                </a>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endset %}
        {# Add the single artworkFile block markup to the array #}
        {% set artworkFileBlocks = artworkFileBlocks|merge([artworkFileBlock]) %}
    {% endswitch %}
{% endfor %}

{# Echo all artworkFile markup in a common container, whereever you need it #}
<div class="wrapper">
    {{ artworkFileBlocks|join('')|raw }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. I wanted to keep the artworkFile block within the Matrix so it can be moved around within the rest of the content.

Comment: Right, that's a valid reason to keep all the block types in a single Matrix field, even if the `artworkFile` blocks aren't output with the other block types.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to affect the `artworkFile` blocks, you could do this:

```
{% case "artworkFile" %}
{% for asset in block.downloadUrl %}
    {% if loop.first %}<div class="wrapper">{% endif %}
    <a href="{{ asset.getUrl() }}" target="_blank">
    <div class="file {{ block.platform }} gutter-bottom--half"></div></a>
    {% if loop.last %}</div>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to wrap all individual fields rather than all. I've updated my questions with more information.